# Median is the mean

Tags: mathematics

Can you divide the numbers 1 to 10 (inclusive) into two sets of 5 numbers each, such that the median of the first set is the mean of the second set, while the mean of the first set is the median of the second set? **Bonus:** can you find different solutions? Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First solution found:

> 3,4,5,8,10
>  1,2,6,7,9

Second one:

> 2,4,5,9,10
>  1,3,6,7,8

Comment: Great work! Both solutions found.

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe, there is no solution possible with 3 numbers at one side to 7 numbers. It would be so nice :)

Comment: You are correct. But 3 and 5 numbers has solutions.